# Sum cone to surface with variable size

Tags: vba

I am trying to develop develop a model to calculate the sum of a cone to row 1 given an array of variable size only if the value of the cell is > 0. 
If the sum is then >=1 I wish to color the range of the cone to display this. If the cone hits the A row boundary I need it not to error and for it to extend in the cone shape the other boundary. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
Public Sub MC()
Worksheets("SC").Cells.Clear
    Dim i&, j&
    For j = 1 To Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 1 To Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, j) > 0 Then
                Worksheets("SC").Cells(i, j).Address , SumAndColorCone(Cells(i, j))
            Else: If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, j) <= 0 Then Worksheets("SC").Cells(i, j) = "0"

            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Public Function SumAndColorCone(r As Range) As Double
    Dim i&, k&, c As Range
    Set c = r
    For i = r.Row - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If r.Column - k < 2 Then Exit For
        Set c = Union(c, r(-k, -k).Resize(, (k + 1) * 2 + 1))
        k = k + 1
    Next
    c.Interior.Color = vbRed
    SumAndColorCone = Application.Sum(c)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub MC()
    Dim c&, i&, j&
    For j = 1 To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If Val(Cells(i, j)) > 0 Then
                c = RGB(Int(Rnd * 255) + 1, Int(Rnd * 255) + 1, Int(Rnd * 255) + 1)
                Debug.Print "Testing value at: " & Cells(i, j).Address & vbLf & "Cone sum: " & SumAndColorCone(Cells(i, j), c) & vbLf
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Private Function SumAndColorCone(r As Range, color&) As Double
    Dim i&, k&, c As Range
    Set c = r
    For i = r.Row - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If r.Column - k < 2 Then
            Set c = Union(c, r(-k, -r.Column + 2).Resize(, r.Column + k + 1))
        Else
            Set c = Union(c, r(-k, -k).Resize(, (k + 1) * 2 + 1))
        End If
        k = k + 1
    Next
    SumAndColorCone = Application.Sum(c)
    If SumAndColorCone > 1 Then c.Interior.color = color
End Function
```